# How many people does it take to keep a secret?

Tags: sociology

On the Wikipedia entry on [Vesna Voluvic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesna_Vulovi%C4%87), who holds the Guiness book work record on  surviving the highest fall without a parachute, a conspiracy theory claiming the plane got shot by the army got debunked as follows:

> One source does not support such conspiracy theories and quotes Czech army expert:
>   In case of violation of the air space, the incident would not be solved by anti-air missiles, but by fighter planes. Also it would not be possible to conceal such incident, as there would approximately 150–200 people knowing about the incident. They would not have any reason to not tell about incident today.

It is not the only claim that debunked the conspiracy theory, so I am not reinstating this conspiracy theory. However, the claim that 150-200 would not be able to keep a secret after such a long time, doesn't look strong to me. I can imagine various intelligence organisation having much more staff at hand.  Is there any evidence or theory that give a general estimate on how many people it takes to keep a secret? I would suspect that number to be quite high, since only Snowden and Assenge comes to mind in modern history, contradicting the Czech source that with 150-200 people it wouldn't be possible to keep a secret.

Comment: How exactly do you expect this to be objectively answered? Sometimes *one person* can't even keep their own secret.

Comment: @meager sure, but there must be risk-assessment models for governments to assess their risk, and it could perfectly be that the number is indeed  below 150.

Comment: "Three may keep a secret, if two of  them are dead." Benjamin Franklin, [Poor Richard's Almanac (1700s, reprinted 1914 USC Pub. Co.)](https://archive.org/stream/poorrichardsalma00franrich/poorrichardsalma00franrich_djvu.txt), Item #559

Comment: Related question: How many people have to know before it's not considered a secret any more?

Comment: @Bobson, Now _that_ is a more interesting question, I think. More suited to philosophy.SE than here, but still an interesting question.